# Can someone explain what the .?.? is doing in self.split('').?.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working on the Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#top) and the challenge is to add a shuffle method to the String class.

This is the suggested solution:

Listing 4.11. Skeleton for a shuffle method attached to the String class:

```
class String
  def shuffle
    self.split('').?.?
  end
end
```

Sorry if this is really easy to most people but I'm new to development.. I don't get what the **.?.?** is doing? It's not explained in the book nor can I find it anywhere online.

Thanks

Comment: self.split('').shuffle.join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the suggested solution - the exercise reads:

`By replacing the question marks in Listing 4.10 with the appropriate methods, combine split, shuffle, and join to write a function that shuffles the letters in a given string.`

`Using Listing 4.11 as a guide, add a shuffle method to the String class.`

You're supposed to replace the `?`'s with the proper method name.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... Here is how it should looks:

**4.10**

```
s.split('').shuffle.join
```

end

**4.11**

```
class String
   def shuffle
     self.split('').shuffle
     end
   end
```